# Does ideal Transformer transfer DC input voltage to secondary side, under NO-Load and Loaded condition?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, electrical

Does ideal Transformer transfer DC input voltage to the secondary side, under NO-Load and Loaded condition? 
 please you take DC input for a long time. Also consider two more conditions, 1st: for permeability tends to infinity, 2nd: permeability is very large finite value, but no loss at all.

Comment: How long has the voltage at the primairy side been in the DC state? Forever, or are we talking about a step response?

Comment: yes, you take DC input for a long time. Also consider two more conditions, 1st: for permeability tends to infinity, 2nd: permeability is very large finite value, but no loss at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you deem to be an ideal transformer.

If the ideal transformer has infinite primary inductance, no saturation, and no primary resistance, then it can carry an arbitrary primary current, and indeed a primary voltage will create a secondary voltage. A secondary load will then cause a secondary and primary current to flow.

If the ideal transformer has no resistance, but a finite inductance and a finite saturation current, then eventually saturation will stop the transformer working.

Comment: but, under the L (inductance) = infinite {due to infinite permeability}, r (resistance ) = 0, for any arbitrary primary current, Will the flux induced in the primary side be constant?

Answer (score 0):

An **ideal** transformer has a defined relationship between the primary and secondary voltages that is equal to the ratio of the number of turns in the windings. An **ideal** transformer doesn't care about time or frequency or flux.